# GStreamer audio pipeline working on Linux but not on Windows

Tags: gstreamer

I set up the following pipelines:

**Server**

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v audiotestsrc ! mulawenc ! tcpserversink host=<IP> port=<PORT>
```

**Client**

```
gst-launch-1.0 tcpclientsrc host=<IP> port=<PORT> ! "audio/x-mulaw, rate=44100, channels=1" ! mulawdec ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! alsasink(windows: directsoundsink)
```

Using a Windows server and a Linux client I only get a sound for a fraction of a second after closing the pipeline (doesn't matter if I close client or server first). When running both server and client on the same Windows machine I get the same result. However, if I run both server and client on the same Linux machine I get the expected result (sin signal).

What do I need to change to make it work on Windows?

Comment: Have a look on the following elements  audioconvert ,audioresample, alsasink; to see if their behaviour differs across Unix and Windows system. Generally, this should not be the case. But sometimes the formats of the received data can be interpreted differently in Windows and Unix, for eg. In case of text files.

Comment: Okay, forgot to mention, that I of course used directsoundsink instead of alsasink on Windows. Will again try all different combinations of audioconvert and audioresample. Thank you for your answer

Comment: nothing worked; I use a Ubuntu VM as client now and everything works perfectly. Caution: If you also want to use this "solution": Use VMware Player, because VirtualBox has issues with sound input (output is working fine, though)